# How to subtract a specific value in tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will need to subtract one value in the tuple by 80 how can I do that?

Before

```
x=(300,400)
```

After

```
newx=(300,320)
```

I have tried looking for list solutions but i'm looking for a simple function to subtract the tuple value

I only need to subtract 1 value in the tuple, not the entire tuple.

Comment: `newx = x[0], x[1] - 80` ???

Comment: is it every time we need to subtract from x[1]?

Comment: yep worked! thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
newx = x[0], x[1] - 80
```

this worked for me thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy package :

```
import numpy

print("Substract result : {} ".format(tuple(numpy.subtract((300,400), (0,80)))))
```

output:

```
Substract result : (300, 320)
```

Answer (score 0):

**tuple is immutable** i.e. you can not change its value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and you are not supposed to modify tuple values. My functions return tuples when I do not expect the "client" to modify the returned values and my functions return lists when I do expect the "client" to modify list's values. If it is you who creates the original tuple - you should reconsider the use of tuples at all if in the end you modify them - lists are more appropriate and `numpy` arrays would be the best due to their simple arithmetical manipulation.